# Flask-admin display image with path from column

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have my DB set like this :

```
  MediaPath    DateCreated    Message   Type
/home/1/1.jpg   21.09.2017              jpeg
/home/2/2.jpg   ....          ....      ....
```

How can i set up Flask code to preview images from the MediaPath column without uploading them to /static/ folder? 
This is usual flask-admin code template:

```
class ImageView(sqla.ModelView):
def _list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name):
    if not model.path:
        return ''

    return Markup('<img src="%s">' % url_for('static',
                                             filename=form.thumbgen_filename(model.path)))

column_formatters = {
    'path': _list_thumbnail
}


form_extra_fields = {
    'path': form.ImageUploadField('Image',
                                  base_path=file_path,
                                  thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the path for the files in the MeidaPath column their absolute path?

Make sure that the path returned by form.thumbgen_filename(model.path) is the absolute path for the file and you can do the following:

**Instead of:**

`return Markup('<img src="%s">' % url_for('static',
    filename=form.thumbgen_filename(model.path)))`

**Use:**

`return Markup('<img src="%s">' % form.thumbgen_filename(model.path))`

** Assuming that the method `thumbgen_filename()` returns the absolute path to the image thumbnail (you haven't posted the code for that method so I assuming that is what the method returns)**

When you use `url_for('static', filename='some-path')` it generate a URL that includes the static path and the files that are inside the static folder depending on the value you provide to url_for's filename argument. If want to load your files using their absolute path, just provide their absolute path without using `url_for()`

Comment: Thank you for answering! However I don`t understand how to use the first column (MediaPath) as a path! 
Can you please write an example on what should I write at "model.path" variable?

Comment: my code example shows you how to do it look at my return statement.I have also updated my answer to show the different return statement you should use

Comment: But how can I write for each model.path = Db('MediaPath')?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Don't you already have the paths stored in your database?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my incorrectness. They are stored in my DB in the first column, called "MediaPath". But what should I write to the "return Markup('<img src="%s">' % form.thumbgen_filename(model.path))" model.path variable to give the link for the "MediaPath" column?

Comment: It should be `return Markup('<img src="%s">' % form.thumbgen_filename(model.MediaPath))` and again this is assuming that  `thumbgen_filename()` will take the path from that column an generate a path for the thumbnail. the `model` argument that is passed to the `_list_thumbnail` formatter gives you access to all the columns. Just use `model.columnName` when you want to access a certain column. In your case, `model.MediaPath`